# Do you miss significant nutrients when juicing?

Tags: diet, nutrition, fruit, juice, vegetables

When juicing fruits and vegies a lot of "solid" pulp are left over. I was wondering if they contain significant nutrients that might be better eaten instead of drinking pure juice?

Comment: Take a look at the Vitamix line of juicers.  I got rid of my centrifugal juicer and got a Vitamix because I was spending a whole bunch of money on fruits and veggies and throwing away the marjority of them in the form of pulp.

Comment: Good question.  If you are interested in nutrition, don't hesitate to join our nutrition proposal here:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Answer (score 3):

A good juicer gets a fair amount of skin, though how much nutrition is lost would depend a lot on the juicer. But it's not just about nutrients, it's about fiber. Fiber serves many purposes, including slowing the absorption of those nutrients and sugars (less insulin spike), and fiber is something the body needs.

I don't see anything *wrong* with juicing, and it's tasty. But IMO it shouldn't be the sole source of fruit and vegetable consumption, because you're missing a lot of what they have to offer, in terms of *both* nutrients and fiber.

All this said, not really a fitness question.

Comment: So I guess eating pulp is good. Well there's actually a lot of questions here relation to nutrition. Is there an SE site specific to nutrition?

Comment: @IMB The charter changed. I don't know if there's a nutrition SE.

Comment: I'm with Dave's answer. Aside from a few specific compounds only found in the rinds or skin of plants, juicing leaves a lot of the nutrition intact. However, as he said, you miss out on the fiber. I believe the FDA recommends no more than 2 servings of fruit/veggies to be replaced with juice.